# Comments not working

Tags: bug, comments

EDIT: Turns out [InvisibleHand](http://www.getinvisiblehand.com/) was breaking it. This is fixed then. Thanks :)

On some questions I am unable to add any comments. This does not go away after reloading the page, but works fine on other questions. For example, I can not add a comment on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16735745/add-null-byte-every-x-byte-in-c) while it works fine [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16735720/why-is-there-a-huge-performance-difference-between-32-and-64-bit-jdk). This happens on StackOverflow, I don't know about the other sites. It does seem to work for other people as I can see comments on both questions. There is no error while adding the comment and I see the link, but nothing happens when I click it. The dev console shows:

```
TypeError: $ is not a function "...ction(c){27==c.which&&a()});$("body").mousedown(function(a){var c=$(a.target);if..."
```

On questions where this happens. I have enough reputation and neither question is locked.

Comment: Are you getting any error while adding comment? or you don't see `add comment` link?

Comment: @hims056 edited.

Comment: Check developer tools in your browser, are there any JavaScript errors?

Comment: Do the textbox appear and the button won't let you post the comment ? Or you can't even get to the textbox ?

Comment: Edited. @returnPhaDaPhunk Like I said, nothing happens. No textbox.

Comment: Try clearing the cache of your browser.

Comment: @hammar Nothing. Still happens. Would've been strange as it's a javascript error.

Comment: @mwerschy: Sometimes an old cached javascript file can cause problems. Anyway, what's your browser? Are you using any extensions/addons/userscripts that might interfere? Try disabling them.

Comment: @hammar Well that was a good idea. InvisibleHand was breaking it. No idea what it's got to do with SO though...